# Fixed position div appears right where sibling div is positioned with margin-top instead of at the top

Tags: html, css

Demo here: http://codepen.io/geoyws/pen/zqobWe

```css
app-header {
  position: fixed;
  /*top: 0px;*/
  /* Without this, app-header appears after the margin of his sibling below. Intuitively you would think that he would ignore his sibling's margin-top and stick at the top without having to state top: 0px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
}
[b] {
  display: block;
}
another-margin {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
margin-generator {
  margin-top: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <app-header b>HEADER</app-header>
  <another-margin b></another-margin>
  <margin-generator b></margin-generator>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? It does not seem intuitive to me at all to affect a fixed positioned element according to a sibling's margin-top.

Comment: I didn't understood what you are trying to say. Please explain in detail. And what is your expected output

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any reference about it, except a tiny example [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/) on example 15, but from experience I can guarantee that `absolute` and `fixed` positioned elements keep their normal position unless set by `top` `right` `bottom` or `left`.

Here is an example:

```css
.abs {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.abs-2 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 60px;
  background: blue;
}
.abs-4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
}
.abs-6 {
  position: fixed;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="abs abs-1"></div>
<div class="abs abs-2"></div>
<div class="abs abs-3"></div>
<div class="abs abs-4"></div>
<div class="abs abs-5"></div>
<div class="abs abs-6"></div>
```

The not red elements are `absolute` or `fixed` positioned with two of the set the `left` property set.